# Model error too small, possible data type problem

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Playing around with sci-kit for the first time. Essentially using multi linear regression to predict a number based on numerical features as well as categories.

My code works (surprising enough ;-)) - however, it works a little bit too well. I get a mean error of less than 1/1000000 on the test set, which can't be true.

I'm new to Python and it feels wrong. Did I do anything incorrectly when it comes to translating between datasets and dataframes? I noticed I had to use [[variable]] a few times to make it work.

```
df = pd.read_csv('train_medium.csv')
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')

y = df[['Income']]

x = df[[ ... columns here ... ]]
cat_columns = [ ... columns here ... ]
x = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix_sep="__", columns=cat_columns)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

regressor = LinearRegression()  
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

coeff_df = pd.DataFrame([[regressor.coef_]], x.columns, columns=['Coefficient'])  
# print(coeff_df)

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': [y_test]['Income'], 'Predicted': [y_pred]})

print('Mean Absolute Error:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))  
print('Mean Squared Error:', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))  
print('Root Mean Squared Error:', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)))
```

Thanks for any ideas, I spent the whole day on this -.-

Comment: how many features and how many data points do you have?

Comment: What's the data? Certainly there's plenty of ways this can happen: Maybe the data really is linear, maybe the scaling is so that any error will be very low, maybe the data has duplicate entries contaminating `y_train` with elements of `y_test`.

Comment: 11 features, 1000 data points in the CSV, but I used one hot encoding, in the model it's 693 features (mostly 1/0). 

Good catch. It's probably just overfitting and I should just rerun with a larger sample e.g. 100k, right?

Comment: Actually no, same problem with 100k data points. And I take out 20% of the data for testing. The problem is something else...